# Python zip numpy arrays of different dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to zip numpy arrays befor saving it via `np.save`. For zipping one dimensional arrays I use

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones(4) * 5.
b = np.ones(4) * 4.
data = np.array(zip(a, b))
```

which does exactly what I want. Now I have more data, say like

```
c = numpy.ones((2, 4))
```

but

```
data = np.array(zip(a, b, c))
```

does not work. I could do

```
data = np.array(zip(a, b, c[0], c[1]))
```

instead, but the "depth" of `c` changes. My solution is

```
data = np.insert(c, 0, b, axis=0)
data = np.insert(data, 0, a, axis=0)
data = zip(*data)
```

but that reads kind of suboptimal. Thanks for an advice.

Comment: avoid using `zip` in connection with `np.array`s. It will turn them into lists, which is highly undesirable as soon as you start wielding larger datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use numpy.hstack/vstack:

```
a = np.ones(4) * 5
b = np.ones(4) * 4
c = np.ones((2, 4))
data = np.vstack([a,b,c]).T
```

*Edit: I actually mostly use np.row_stack/column_stack nowadays, as I find it more natural than hstack or vstack:*

```
    data = np.column_stack([a,b,c.T])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `*` opertor to "unpack" `c` when calling `zip`:

```
data = np.array(zip(a, b, *c))
data.shape
=> (4, 4)
```

(You can avoid `zip` and use a direct numpy approach (e.g. using `vstack`, as @metaperture suggested), which is arguably a better approach. However, this answer demostrates the correct way to do exactly what you were trying to do originally)

Answer (score 2):

I would *not* recommend using `zip` if your only objective is to save multiple arrays of different dimensions, as the title of this question suggests. Use [`np.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) or [`np.savez_compressed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed) instead. These functions were meant to save multiple arrays (of arbitrary dimensions).

Using `zip` is particularly bad as it won't port to [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), where `zip` returns an *iterator* and not a list of tuples. Calling `np.array` on the iterator creates an array with a single element of dtype `object`, which is probably not what you want.
I was not able to recover the zipped data after a save and a load.